# Oracle: VLOOKUP Equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle, vlookup

I have a view like this:

```
col_1  col_2  my_date
-----  -----  -------
1      5      2011
2      6      2014
3      7      2012
4      8      2011
```

And a table like this:

```
date_1  date_2  the_value
------  ------  ---------
2010    2012    v1
2013    2015    v2
```

I want something like the Excel VLOOKUP function that find the value (`the_value`) which `my_date` is between `date_1` and `date_2`, so I can have a result like this:

```
col_1  col_2  my_date  the_value
-----  -----  -------  ---------
1      5      2011     v1
2      6      2014     v2
3      7      2012     v1
4      8      2011     v1
```

The type of date columns are `DATE`. These are sample data for simplicity.

Comment: Why don't you use between clause by joining these two tables?

Comment: You can join these two table on "my_date between date_1 and date_2", however that can duplicate your rows. If you want the exact functioning of vlookup, you can group by the columns in your first table and use First_Value(the_value) did you try that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a join in SQL with a `between` rather than an equality join condition.

```
select t1.col_1, t1.col_2, t1.my_date, t2.the_value
from table_one t1
  join table_two t2 on t1.my_date between t2.date_1 and t2.date_2;
```

Note that `between` *includes* the boundaries so it would also return rows where `my_date` is `2010`. If you don't want that you need to use a join condition with `>` and `<`:

```
select t1.col_1, t1.col_2, t1.my_date, t2.the_value
from table_one t1
  join table_two t2 on t1.my_date > t2.date_1 
                   and t1.my_date < t2.date_2;
```

This also requires your "date" ranges to be non-overlapping, otherwise you'd get some strange results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated query to fetch the value:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT s.the_value FROM t2 s
        WHERE t.my_date between s.date_1 and s.date_2) as the_value
FROM t1 t
```